# C# Linq to Objects/Syntax and Effectively searching if a collection members exist in another collection of sub-collections

Tags: c#, search, hyperlink

I have the first collection of numbers: `(1,3,5,6,23)`

and the second collection of collections of 1 to n integers

```
(3),    (6,1),    (1,3,5,23,6,14,67),    (2,3)
```

So the second collection has elements a, b, c and d which themselves are a collection of integers

```
a=(3), b=(6,1), c=(1,3,5,23,6,14,67), d=(2,3)
```

So this can be basically a jagged array)

How to do Linq to object queries using both extension method syntax, and query expression syntax
to find out what combination of numbers in the first collection can be found in collection of a, b, c or d or nowhere. In other words which numbers from the second collection are contained in the first collection.

Q1: I would like to see `a=(3), b=(6,1)` being found since the members of each collection a and b c exist in the first collection.

Q2: I would like to see the opposite case where we start from the second collection and try to find if its sub collection members belong to the first collection.

I would like to know pros and cons of both approaches. In actuality I will deal with thousands of collections with up to 10 numbers in each.

Comment: Your specification is inconsistent or incomplete: `c` contains some elements not in the original, just as `d` yet you want `c` only to be found.  And though `c` is a pure superset, `a` and `b` are not; so that doesn't seem to be it either - what exactly *are* you looking for?

Comment: @eamon-nerbonne. You are right. I made corrections based on your suggestions. Is it clear now?  Thanks Rad

Comment: Yep, it's clear now!  Do you have any info on the distribution of these numbers? e.g. that they're typically below 100 or that the prob. of seeing number `n` is proportional to `log n`, or some such thing?

Comment: Oh, and you say "collection" - do you mean set, as in that you only care about the absence or presence of a number in the collection, not how frequently it occurs nor the collection's ordering?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand Q2: do you mean that you'd like to find all super-sets of the original set; e.g. only `c`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
int[] firstSet = new[] { 1,3,5,6,23 };
int[][] secondSet = new[] 
{
    new [] { 3 },
    new [] { 6, 1 },
    new [] { 1,3,5,23,6,14,67 },
    new [] { 2, 3}
};

// only subsets where each member matces a member of the first set
var matchinSubSets = from subset in secondSet
                     where subset.All(x => firstSet.Contains(x))
                     select subset;
```

As for performance, dont worry about that to much, if you're only gonna match thousands of entries, it will be done calculating before you know it

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Have a try of these:

```
var xs = new [] { 1, 3, 5, 6, 23, };
var yss = new []
{
    new [] { 3, },
    new [] { 6, 1, },
    new [] { 1, 3, 5, 23, 6, 14, 67, },
    new [] { 2, 3, },
};
```

I'll answer your second question first:

```
var q2 =
    from ys in yss
    where !ys.Except(xs).Any()
    select ys;

var q2b = yss.Where(ys => !ys.Except(xs).Any());
```

These two queries are identical - except one is in LINQ and the other in extension method syntax. The compiler will generate the same code for both.

Question one is a nightmare - much harder to do.

```
var q1 =
    from z in yss.Zip(
        xs.Aggregate(
            yss.AsEnumerable(),
            (_yss, x) => (
                from ys in _yss
                select ys.Except(new [] { x }).ToArray())),
        (ys, _ys) => new { ys, _ys })
    where !z._ys.Any()
    select z.ys;

var q1b =
    yss.Zip(
        xs.Aggregate(
            yss.AsEnumerable(),
            (_yss, x) => _yss
                .Select(ys =>
                    ys.Except(new [] { x }).ToArray())),
        (ys, _ys) => new { ys, _ys })
    .Where(z => !z._ys.Any())
    .Select(z => z.ys);
```

Again both in LINQ and extension method syntax and both compiled to the same code.

I ran some performance tests and the "q2" queries are over 10x faster to complete than the "q1" queries.

In one test I had `xs` with 61 distinct elements, `yss` with 100,000 distinct valued sub-collections with 956,512 elements in total and the "q1" queries ran in 5,354.1 milliseconds & "q2" ran in 302.1 milliseconds - 17.7x factor.

However, drop this to `xs` of 10 & `yss` with 10,000 & 95,641 then the results were 115.3 & 7.4 milliseconds respectively. Either approach would probably be fast enough.

Comment: The OP has clarified his question now.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - Updated my answer based on OP's question change.

Comment: Hmm, I see you've interpreted his question differently; I took q1 to be "find all subsets" and q2 to be "find all supersets"; you're taking both to be "find all subsets" but with a different approach thus different perf.